# Using \autoref in IEEE article templates

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ref

I'm writing an article in the IEEE conference template. In the instructions to the use of this template, is written that equations must be referenced in the text as for exemple: "(1)", and figures as "Fig. 1". However, when I use \autoref{}, what I got is "Equation 1" and "Figure 1".
How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To cross-reference `equation` objects in the desired format -- without the "equation" label but with parentheses surrounding the equation number -- use `\eqref` (provided by the `amsmath` package), not `\autoref`.
- To cross-reference `figure` objects, run the following instruction in the preamble (*after* loading `hyperref`):

  ```
  \renewcommand\figureautorefname{Fig.}
  ```

  and then use `\autoref` as usual in the body of the document.